# Panda to CSV all the data is not getting written

Tags: html, pandas, csv

I am exporting HTML table to CSV using pandas. The code is as follows:

```
`myhtml=browser.page_source
 print myhtml
 time.sleep(10)
 df = pd.read_html(myhtml)
 data1=pd.DataFrame(df)
 with open('my_csv.csv', 'a') as f:
        data1.to_csv(f)
```

the data is being written to csv but not all the data . For example for data of 383 rows , first 20 rows are being written and ...... is be inserted then last 100 rows are written. I want all the row to be written to csv for later use.

Please help.

–--/---+----------/-__;_+++++++++++++++++++++
I got  solution by adding pd.set option for display max columns,rows